# Processing Callback Options not working in jQuery File Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I'm using blueimp's jQuery File Upload and I'm trying to display what image is being uploaded at the moment (only the index, "Image 1 is being uploaded" for example).

I tried to use process to change a span element so it is displayed, but it did nothing. The option sequentialUploads is set to true.

I tried both

```
.bind('fileuploadprocess', function (e, data) {
  alert(data.index);
});
```

and

`process:function(e,data){
    alert(data.index);
}`

None of them worked. Tried others like processdone and processalways, but they did nothing also.

Thank you so much ❤

Comment: FYI, `.bind()` is deprecated, you should use `.on()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
.on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {/* ... */})
```

For successful upload requests (*will also be called if the server returns a JSON response with an error property*)

Example:

```
function (e, data) {
    // data.result
    // data.textStatus;
    // data.jqXHR;
}
```

*Read the official documentation